# Satisfying Properties of nodes after rotation in AVL trees

Tags: python, data-structures, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

I was learning about Self Balanced BST & AVL Trees and I am stuck at a particular case when x = z. [image: AVL PROPERTIES]

I have this example for better understanding:
[image]

As you may see according to the properties --> all the elements >= node x, should be on right subtree of node x, but In this case 3 will be on left subtree of node x which violates the properties of BST.

I may be wrong at something since I am learning about Data Structures using online resources on my own, It would be really helpful if you could answer this question, And correct me If I am wrong at something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually binary search trees do not have duplicate elements, so this problem is avoided.

Comment: my quesion is, what if we have have such a case will it be able to balance itself according to AVL trees??